# Conductor.Collection.OneActive view not loaded

Tags: caliburn.micro, caliburn

I have a Conductor.Collection.OneActive view model, which in initial state has ActiveItem null, when I set the item eventually (loaded based on user input), the view is loaded fine, but initially I just see an empty space in my UI, which is not nice.
Any ideas how to work around that besides creating empty item initially?

Answer (score -1):

There can be some reasons of this behavior. Can you provide a fragment of your Conductor? Did you add your conductor items to `Items` property? Did you call `ActivateItem(...)` method? Which method did you use to initialize your conductor? If you overridden `OnInitialize` method, make sure `base.OnInitialize` inside is launched.

Comment: No, I didn't call ActivateItem - as I do not have an item to activate yet. In the end I ended up with creating empty view models for each item (I have the hierarchy of conductors here :D)